# Twilio блокировка сообщений

Tags: php, javascript

Что-то не могу найти в twilio, где у них в API описывалось, как я могу заблокировать подключение к каналу определенных пользователей. Может кто сталкивался с таким и как вы решили эту проблему?

Comment: на сколько я понял,* twilio *- это сервис смс-рассылки??? Что имеется в виду под "заблокировать подключение к каналу определенных пользователей"

Comment: там не только смс рассылка. у них еще есть отдельный сервис для реалтайм сообщений.
вот допустим есть два пользователя и один из них решил заблокировать сообщения от другого пользователя, т.е. как-то нужно на стороне сервиса запрещать отправлять сообщения при добавлении в "черный список", но там об этом вообще не слова. там только можно исключить пользователя из канала, но ничего не мешает создать другому пользователю новый канал для сообщений первому пользователю

Comment: тогда что мешает у себя вести этот черный список, и если человек в черном списке, то не отравлять запросы к API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-то поможет, то вот что написали мне из техподдержки

> Jim Madden (Twilio): We do not currently provide a way for
>   blacklisting users through the API. You will need to write your own
>   application logic to handle this type of scenario. Your chat
>   application will be giving out tokens, which you could use to revoke
>   or block a user. As of now we do not have a mechanism in the API, or
>   directions for blacklisting users.

Их сервис не имеет такой возможности. Грубо говоря, нам нужно делать для этого отдельную таблицу с пермишинами между пользователями. Итого у нас получается 2 токена: первый для доступа к самому twilio, а второй для пермишинов между пользователями. Если я правильно понимаю...